# Empty field in ActiveAdmin Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I have a form of ActiveAdmin but i cant validate de empty fields, i need show a message or something. My form is:

```
form multipart: true do |f|
  f.inputs "Organización" do
    f.input :nombre, :label => "Nombre"
    f.input :descripcion, :label => "Descripción" 
    f.input :banner, as: :file, hint: image_tag(f.object.banner.url), label: "Banner"
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Maybe is necesary edit the controller but i dont know how i can do it

I appreciate any cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the validations on the model itself e.g.

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of: :nombre, :descripcion, :banner


end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was helpful